# Cloud function for firebase being fired too many times

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

We have an android app which collects users' location every 30 seconds and writes it to Firebase Realtime database. I want to execute a cloud function on firebase if the user's location has not changed for 15 minutes.

Initial approach: 
Have the android app make a HTTP call to invoke the cloud function every 15 minutes.

Problem with the approach:
There are 1000 active users and expected to grow to 10,000 this approach would result in firing 960,000 (1000 users * 4 requests per hour * 24 hours) times every day.

The purpose of location is that if it has not changed after 15 min., the cloud function sends a notification to a web client.
The mobile phones operate in low connectivity and are low-end devices so it is not viable to have the mobile trigger a notification.

The goal is to minimise the number of cloud functions to be fired.

What could be the right approach so that number of cloud function invocations is minimised?

Comment: You might need to rephrase your question because at the moment it isn't clear what your problem is.

Comment: It seems to me that the best way of knowing if the device hasn't moved is by detecting that on the device itself, since it has the GPS.  Why do you need to a backend to determine this?

Comment: You are right. As also suggested by@vershov. The backend is not the best place to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution your are asking is depending on the context of the  position data usage.

- If it's just a statistic, you could cache the position data locally and push it into a cloud from time to time.
- If the position data is used to provide a service based on, it's up to you to decide based on algorithms implemented.

Comment: The purpose of location is that if it has not changed after 15 min., the cloud function sends a notification to a web client.

Comment: @YashSharma, if so, why can't you track client location locally and, after 15 mins of being in the same location, triggers the cloud functionality from the client?

Comment: It turns out this actually is the right approach. Doing it on mobile is straightforward.On the backend it does not seem feasible.